# Putting a readonly title in a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How do I put `readonly` text inside a `UITextField`.  For example, the "Name" and "Security" fields in the iPod touch "Other networks" settings contain, respectively, the words "Name" and "Security", with an editable area to the right.  `UITextField` has a "placeholder" property but that disappears as soon as I type.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put this line where `txtname` is object of `UITextField`:

```
txtName.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: That does make the textfield text uneditable, but the original question was about having an attached label before the textfield without having to create a second control. +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing in those fields is not that the UITextField has a label but that the UITableViewCell has two controls on it - a label and a textfield without a border.

Comment: I only need to have two textfields so I was hoping to avoid having to implement a UITableView.

Comment: It's not really wrong or hard to implement a UITableView to host two text fields - and having control over the UITableViewCell for labels is a bonus.

Comment: You actually don't need to implement a UITableView. Just add a UILabel and a UITextField (without border)

Answer (score 0):

Position a UILabel inside of your UITextField's frame where you want, then set the UITextFields "leftView" property to the UILabel. Make sure you set the UITextFields "leftViewMode" property to UITextFieldViewModeAlways

The Code should look something like this..

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44)];
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, textField.frame.size.height)];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
label.text = @"Name:";
textField.leftView = label;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```